# replaceAll on hasmap key starting with a $

Tags: java, regex, hashmap

I store values in a key/value hashmap. When the value of a key starts with a $, and I do a regex replaceAll call, an exception is thrown.
Any idea why and how I should prevent this exception? There is no error when the value contains/starts with 'normal' text

```
public static String ReplaceVariables(String argumentValue){
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{.*?\\}"); // find any text surrendered by "${" and "}"
    while (true)
    {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(argumentValue);
        if (!m.find()){
            break; // no match found
        }
        String varName = m.group();
        String varValue = GlobalUtilities.getVariable(varName); //get the hashmap value of the "varName" key
        argumentValue = m.replaceAll(varValue); // replace all ${....} found by its hashmap value
    }
    return argumentValue; // return the new string
}
```

Comment: What exception does it throw?

Comment: Does your replacement string contain backslashes or dollar signs? Also, I think that you replace all occurrences of `${...}` with the corresponding hashmap value for the first occurrence.

Comment: I suppose you get NPE when calling `replaceAll`, and the reason is that your hashmap does not contain corresponding key/value pair. Check that `varValue` is not null before passing it to `replaceAll` method.

Comment: Use `Matcher.quoteReplacement` to quote any dollar signs or backslashes: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement(java.lang.String) (Markdown eats the closing parenthesis at the end of this link...)

Answer (score 0):

I had to add "\" to the returned key value when starting with a $, and changed .replaceAll with .replaceFirst :)

Thanks for the hints guys!